# Using setTimeout inside a for loop - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a setTimeout inside the a for loop, but it not behaving as i anticipated.

I have a bunch of banners in a page that are loading all at once. I am removing their parent's div html and storing it in an array. Then I would like for each parent to receive its corresponding html every 5 seconds. This only needs to happen once on ready state.

Here's my code...

```js
function oneBanner() {

   var divs = $('.banner-slide'),
       imgs = [];

   for ( var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++ ) {
      imgs.push( $('.banner-slide:nth-child(' + (j+1) + ')') );
   }

   for ( var k = 0; k < imgs.length; k++ ) {
      var url = $(imgs[k]).html();
      $(imgs[k]).html('');

      setTimeout(function(y) {
         console.log(k * 5000);
         $(imgs[k]).html(url);
      }, k * 5000, k);
      
   }
}
oneBanner();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-slide">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/150/150" >
</div>

<div class="banner-slide">
  <a href="#"> <img src="http://fillmurray.com/150/150" > </a>
</div>

<div class="banner-slide">
  <img src="http://stevensegallery.com/150/150" >
</div>
```

As you can see the images do not get printed on the screen one at a time every 5 seconds - which I thought I was doing.

Thank you for any help.

Serge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better to simplify your code while you don't need any of variables/arrays outside this function .. you can just use jquery `.each()`

try This

```
function oneBanner() {
   var divs = $('.banner-slide');
   divs.each(function(i){  // loop through .banner-slide divs
      var ThisIt = $(this);  // define this outside setTimout function
      setTimeout(function(){
         divs.hide();    // hide all .banner-slide divs
         ThisIt.show();  // show just this one
      } , 5000 * i);     // time * the i -- i is the index of the div
   }); 
}
```

see the code in action

```js
function oneBanner() {
   var divs = $('.banner-slide');
   divs.each(function(i){
      var ThisIt = $(this);
      setTimeout(function(){
         divs.hide();
         ThisIt.show();
      } , 5000 * i);
   }); 
}

oneBanner();
```

```css
.banner-slide:not(:first){
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-slide">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/150/150" >
</div>

<div class="banner-slide">
  <a href="#"> <img src="http://fillmurray.com/150/150" > </a>
</div>

<div class="banner-slide">
  <img src="http://stevensegallery.com/150/150" >
</div>
```

> **Note**: by using `setTimeout()` you'll show each image for 5 seconds and the code will stop looping

**Update**  *up to the OP comment*

```js
function oneBanner() {
   var divs = $('.banner-slide'),
       htmlArray = [];
   divs.each(function(i){
      var ThisIt = $(this);            // get this outside the setTimout
      htmlArray.push(ThisIt.html());   // push the inner html to the array
      ThisIt.html('');                 // emty this div
      setTimeout(function(){
         $(ThisIt).html(htmlArray[i]); // add html again with setTimeout every 5 second to its parent div
      } , 5000 * i);
   });
}

oneBanner();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-slide">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/150/150" >
</div>

<div class="banner-slide">
  <a href="#"> <img src="http://fillmurray.com/150/150" > </a>
</div>

<div class="banner-slide">
  <img src="http://stevensegallery.com/150/150" >
</div>
```

Comment: I don't need to "show" each every 5 seconds. Once the page loads I need to remove each parent's html and store it in an array. THEN every 5 seconds re-insert them back into their original place. And it has to be the entire inner html - either just the img tag or the img and anchor. I hope this makes sense lol.

Comment: @Sergio I updated my answer with comment on code .. please read it .. Have  a great day :-)

Comment: Great. Thanks Again. You as well, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

one word: closure

```js
function oneBanner() {

   var divs = $('.banner-slide'),
       imgs = [];

   for ( var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++ ) {
      imgs.push( $('.banner-slide:nth-child(' + (j+1) + ')') );
   }
   
   imgs.forEach(($img,k)=>{
 var url = $img.html();
   $img.html('');

   setTimeout(function(y) {
   $img.html(url);
   }, k * 5000, k);
 })
 
}
oneBanner();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-slide">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/150/150" >
</div>

<div class="banner-slide">
  <a href="#"> <img src="http://fillmurray.com/150/150" > </a>
</div>

<div class="banner-slide">
  <img src="http://stevensegallery.com/150/150" >
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain. Your code sort of works in my real application, but do you mean by "closure".

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong variable inside of your setTimeout. Replace 'y' with 'k'

```js
  function oneBanner() {

     var divs = $('.banner-slide'),
         imgs = [];

     for ( var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++ ) {
        imgs.push( $('.banner-slide:nth-child(' + (j+1) + ')') );
     }

     for ( var k = 0; k < imgs.length; k++ ) {
        var url = $(imgs[k]).html();
        $(imgs[k]).html('');
        setTimeout(function(k) {
           console.log(k * 5000);
           $(imgs[k]).html(url);
        }, k * 5000, k);

     }
  }
  oneBanner();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="banner-slide">
      <img src="http://www.placecage.com/150/150" >
    </div>

    <div class="banner-slide">
      <a href="#"> <img src="http://fillmurray.com/150/150" > </a>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-slide">
      <img src="http://stevensegallery.com/150/150" >
    </div>
```